# SASS - Nested Parent Selector Concatenation?

Tags: sass

Okay, this is the output I want to get:

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3 {
    z-index: 1;
}

.class-1-et-cetera, .class-2-et-cetera, .class-3-et-cetera {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

And I want to get it by nesting a selector and using SASS' really awesome `&` to grab the parent selectors. So I've been trying something like this (SASS-syntax first):

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3
    z-index: 1
    &-et-cetera
        z-index: 5
```

SCSS Syntax:

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3 {
    z-index: 1;
    &-et-cetera {
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
```

Only problem is, that doesn't work. I tried messing with the text after the `&`... things like `&#{"-et-cetera"}`, `&#{-et-cetera}`, `& + "-et-cetera"`... you get the idea.

Figured it'd be possible, but can't seem to find it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider taking advantage of the fact that elements can have more than one class.

```
<div class="class-1 et-cetera"></div>
<div class="class-1"></div>
<div class="class-2 et-cetera"></div>
<div class="class-3"></div>
...
```

---

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3
  z-index: 1

.et-cetera 
  z-index: 5
```

This is less CSS, using Sass or otherwise.

If you need the extra specificity, you can always nest it like this:

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3
  z-index: 1
  &.et-cetera 
    z-index: 5
```

Which would give you:

```
.class-1, .class-2, .class-3 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.class-1.et-cetera, .class-2.et-cetera, .class-3.et-cetera {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

#### Edit

If you *really* want to do it with Sass, you could do this, which I don't recommend:

```
%class
  z-index: 1

%etc
  z-index: 5

@each $i in class-1, class-2, class-3
  .#{$i}
    @extend %class
  .#{$i}-et-cetera
    @extend %etc
```

I think it's much easier, flexible, and future-proof to just use two different classes.

Comment: Awesome! _Should_ have worked perfectly, except it seems LiveReload's SASS is outdated enough to not recognize placeholders... But with one simple tweak, it worked. I just had to replace `%class` and `%etc` with `.class` and `.etc`. Thank you!

Comment: And yes, for posterity's sake it's good that you mention the use of multiple classes and best practices—I just happen to be doing something really weird and experimental/hacky and have to abide by the classes generated by the custom icon font I'm exploiting to render css-alterable vector art. :P